# Libgdx actor following a Parabolic movement

Tags: java, libgdx, bezier

I want to move an actor A from position x1, y1 to position x2, y2 but with a **parabolic movement**.

Should I use a [bezier curve](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Bezier.html) ?

Is there any example I could take a look at? In the tests project I only saw a linear movement (in PathTest example).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Bezier curve is cubic, it is not parabolic.**

You could use following [**`Action`**](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#actions) in stead.

```
protected void update (float percent) {
    actor.setPosition(startX + (endX - startX) * percent,
                      startY + (endY - startY) * percent * percent,
                      alignment);
}
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. If start point is (x=500,y=0) and final point is (0,0 bottom left corner) I'd like the object goes first to about (x=250, y=250), and with that action I don't see how to do it, the movement of the actor is a little bit weird. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, Bezier curve can be of any degree.